# file list with hash, inode and name

Tags: bash

I want a command that outputs a list of all files in a directory tree. The columns should be: hash, inode, filename.

**Something like ls -iRAw2 and add a column for the hash.**

I have build this solution and the result is almost what I want:

```
find testpath -type f -printf 'x%i %p\n' -exec sha1sum {} + \
|awk '{print $2,$1}' \
|sort \
|awk 'ORS=NR%2?" ":"\n"' \
|awk '{print $2,substr($4,2),$1}'
```

The only problem is that 'sort' obv. ignores blanks and dots.

The 'x' printed by find makes sure that the sort always puts the hash line before the inode line. It is later stripped by the substr.

But I don't really like the solution. It is too complex, not elegant and uses awk. I'd rather have something using only internal bash commands.

I have searched solutions to

```
'ls -i' and add a hash column somehow.
'find' as above and add a hash column.
'sha1sum' and add an inode column.
```

But nothing worked out. What would be a more elegant way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Does your script even work?

Comment: Yes, you can try. But there's one problem left I am currently researching. The sort doesn't distinguish a blank and a dot in the strings. Can you tell me the option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more readable version :

```
find testpath -type f -printf "%i " -exec sha1sum {} \; |\
while read -r inode sha1sum file; do
    echo "$sha1sum $inode $file"
done
```

Comment: That's fantastic!

Comment: Didn't know read -r yet, and without the while loop, find -exec doesn't output the %i, but now I can still access it. Thank you.